# Proof Review: Fundamental group abelian if and only if isomorphisms are equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I was hoping someone could review my proof for correctness. Thanks in advance!

**Problem:** Let x$_0$ and x$_1$ be points of the path-connected space X. Show that $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) is abelian if and only if for every pair $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of paths from x$_0$ and x$_1$, we have $\hat{\alpha}$ = $\hat{\beta}$

Note: $\hat{\alpha}$ is the isomorphism from $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) to $\pi_1$(X,x$_1$) via the usual map using a path from x$_0$ to x$_1$.

**Solution:**

For the forward direction, suppose $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) is abelian. Then since $\hat{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism we have that $\pi_1$(X,x$_1$) is also abelian. Then we have the following:

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$) = ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$)

Then using the fact that $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) is also abelian we have:

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$ $\cdot$ $\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $\beta$) =  ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$ $\cdot$ $\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$)

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$ ) =  ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$)

Using the homomorphism property we have:

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$) = ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$)

Which yields:

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$) = ($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f^{-1}$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$)

Which gives:

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$) = ($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$  $\alpha$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f^{-1}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$) $\cdot$ ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\beta$)

=> ($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$ ) =  ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$  $\cdot$ $\beta$)

And so $\hat{\alpha}$ = $\hat{\beta}$

**This part is wrong up to the horizontal line:**

But we have that  ($f$ $\cdot$ $f$) is homotopic to $f$ since:

Let i$_2$(s) = { (2s) for s $\in$ [0,$\frac{1}{2}$] and (2s -1) for s $\in$ [$\frac{1}{2}$,1] }, where i$_2$: [0,1] -> [0,1]. Also let i: [0,1] -> [0,1] be the identity map. Then since [0,1] is convex, we have i$_2$ is homotopic to $i$ via the straight-line homotopy. Then we have f $\circ$ i$_2$ is homotopic to f $\circ$ $i$ which implies $f$ $\cdot$ $f$ is homotopic to f. Then we have now established:

($\bar{\alpha}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\alpha$ ) =  ($\bar{\beta}$ $\cdot$ $f$  $\cdot$ $\beta$)

Hence $\hat{\alpha}$ = $\hat{\beta}$.

---

For the reverse direction, suppose $\hat{\alpha}$ = $\hat{\beta}$ and that X is path connected. Now since X is path connected we have that all fundamental groups, $\pi_1$(X,x$_j$) are isomorphic, for any x$_j$ $\in$ X. Suppose $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) is not abelian. Then there exists and $f$,$g$ $\in$ $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) such that f and g do not commute. Then $g$ is a loop from x$_0$ to x$_0$ but can be written as follows:

Let $\phi$ be the path from x$_0$ to $w$ for some $w$ $\in$ image($g$), where the path $\phi$ follows the loop $g$ up to some point $w$ $\ne$ x$_0$. And let $\delta$ be the path from x$_0$ to $w$ using the remainder of the loop $g$. Note that such a $w$ $\ne$ x$_0$ exists since if $g$ is the constant loop onto x$_0$ then $g$ = e$_{x_0}$ and g must commute with f, a contradiction to the case we are in.

Then we have $g$ = $\phi$ $\cdot$ $\bar{\delta}$. Then using the equivalence of $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\delta}$ we have: $\bar{\phi}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\phi$ = $\bar{\delta}$ $\cdot$ $f$ $\cdot$ $\delta$, which implies that we have $f$ $\cdot$ $\phi$ $\cdot$ $\bar{\delta}$ = $\phi$ $\cdot$ $\bar{\delta}$ $\cdot$ $f$, which in turn implies $f$ $\cdot$ $g$ = $g$ $\cdot$ $f$, a contradiction. Hence the fundamental group with base point x$_0$ must be abelian.

Note that we have the equivalence of $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\delta}$ as both are derived from paths from x$_0$ to $w$, with both points in X, and hence by hypothesis the isomorphisms they induce between the groups $\pi_1$(X,x$_0$) and $\pi_1$(X,$w$) are equivalent, namely $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\delta}$. **(is this a correct interpreation of the hypothesis or are x$_0$ and x$_1$ fixed?)**

Comment: The proof of the first statement is not correct, assuming $f$ is meant to be an arbitrary loop based at $x_0$. The corresponding group theoretic statement is that $x^2 = x$, which would imply that $x$ is the identity. But the fundamental group can definitely have more than one element!

Comment: @RyleeLyman, I think I've corrected my solution to the first part, does that look better?

Comment: For the second part why not just take $x_0=x_1$? Then $\alpha\in\pi_1(X;x_0)$ and $\widehat\alpha$ is the map $f\mapsto \alpha\cdot f\cdot\alpha^{-1}$. By assumption this is the same as $\hat\ast=id$. Hence $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is abelian.

Comment: Why two questions? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3582030

Comment: @PaulFrost. I voted to close this one

Comment: nope, i posted that. see above

Comment: @H_1317 for the second part, you don't have to use proof by contradiction.